# SignIn using twitter

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to implement **SingIn Using Twitter** in my `node.js app`. First I have called `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`, twitter give me `oauth_token` and then I'm calling `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN` which open a new window that is shown that user can accept this app for signIn. After user accept, twitter call a `callback url` with `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`. Now I call `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token` to get `access_token`. And I get `access_token` as like as given format

```
{ 
   oauth_token: 'NEW_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN',
   oauth_token_secret: 'NEW_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET',
   user_id: 'TWITTER_USER_ID',
   screen_name: 'TWITTER_SCREEN_NAME',
   x_auth_expires: '0' 
}
```

Now I'm trying to get more user information like `user_email, user_pic etc`. I'm calling the following api `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json` with following parameter:

```
 let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', 'thisIsTest');
 hmac.update(uuid.v4());
 let hash = hmac.digest('hex');

 var profileOauth = {
    oauth_consumer_key: 'twitter_consumer_key',
    oauth_nonce: uuid.v4(),
    oauth_signature_method:'HMAC-SHA1',
    oauth_signature: hash,
    oauth_timestamp: Date.parse(new Date()),
    oauth_version: '1.0',
    oauth_token: 'twitter_accessToken_oauth_token'
  };

  request.get({
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json',
    // qs: { include_email: true },
    oauth: profileOauth,
    json: true
  }, function(err2, resp, profile) {

    console.log("profile 1 :  ", profile);
    res.json(profile);

  });
```

And I'm getting the following error :

```
  profile 1 :   { errors: [ { code: 215, message: 'Bad Authentication data.' } ] }
```

Any suggestion?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var profileOauth = {
oauth_consumer_key: 'twitter_consumer_key',
oauth_nonce: uuid.v4(),
oauth_signature_method:'HMAC-SHA1',
oauth_signature: hash,
oauth_timestamp: Date.parse(new Date()),
oauth_version: '1.0',
oauth_token: 'twitter_accessToken_oauth_token'
};
```

Try replacing above code with this

```
var profileOauth = {
oauth_consumer_key: 'twitter_consumer_key',
oauth_consumer_key_secret: 'twitter_consumer_key_secret', //add consumer_key secret
oauth_nonce: uuid.v4(),
oauth_signature_method:'HMAC-SHA1',
oauth_signature: hash,
oauth_timestamp: Date.parse(new Date()),
oauth_version: '1.0',
oauth_token: 'twitter_accessToken_oauth_token',
oauth_token_secret: 'oauth_token_secret' // add oauth_token_secret
};
```

I think you forgot to include App consumer key secret and user oauth token secret in your parameter list.